# Defining defaul command run via npx

Tags: npm, package.json, npx

I am using the `bin` property of `package.json` to define commands to be launched via a certain package.

I have a package, **my-package**, whose `package.json` has something like this

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ....
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "command_1": "./dist/lib/command_1.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

I publish the package and, when I run `npx my-package` I see that `command_1.js` gets executed as expected.

Now I add a second command like this

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ....
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "command_1": "./dist/lib/command_1.js",
    "command_2": "./dist/lib/command_2.js",
  },
  ...
}
```

Now if I run `npx my-package` the **default command** that gets exectued is still `command_1.js`, while if I run `npx -p my-package command_2` I execute `command_2.js`.

Now I would like to have a third command, `command_0.js` to become the **default command** to be executed. So I try positioning `command_0` as the first entry in the `bin` property like this

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ....
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "command_0": "./dist/lib/command_0.js",
    "command_1": "./dist/lib/command_1.js",
    "command_2": "./dist/lib/command_2.js",
  },
  ...
}
```

but what I see is that the default command is still `command_1`. So my question is how is it possible to set a new default command?

Comment: This is just a speculation. The `bin` is an object, and iterating over an object with `for...in` loop does not guarantee any particular order, and perhaps that's what **npm** does.

Answer (score 0):

Reading more carefully [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx#description), it seems that the right way to set a default command is to use in entry in the `bin` property which matches the unscoped name of the package.

So, using the example presented in the question, the `package.json` should look like this

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ....
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "my-package": "./dist/lib/command_0.js",
    "command_0": "./dist/lib/command_0.js",
    "command_1": "./dist/lib/command_1.js",
    "command_2": "./dist/lib/command_2.js",
  },
  ...
}
```

Just for the sake of completion, the documentation states *"if there are no bin entries, or none of them match the name of the package, then npm exec exits with an error"*. In my case, it seems that even if *"none of them (the bin entries) match the name of the package"* there is no error raised by `npx`, on the contrary one of the entries is selected with no clear selection criteria.